# CronJob - Laravel 5.4 - Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a problem with CronJob in Laravel 5.4 with MySQL and Eloquent.

When I execute `php artisan schedule:run` I get the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  could not find driver (SQL: select ...... )


[PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

But, all drivers are installed. The application work perfect. If I copy all code in a controller and I make a route, all code works perfect too.

In local (Mac), also work perfect the `schedule:run`

The only problem is with cron job, it doesn't find the driver.

Something that I'm missing?

PD: I made a command too `php artisan testing:code` and the same error. The query is made by Eloquent, but still don't find the driver.

Thanks

Comment: I am hoping you have read the docs for task scheduling and run this command * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I read it, but the cronjob doesn't work because I have that error. So I try manually.

Comment: try running `mysql -v` on terminal to check if mysql is already installed

Comment: It is installed. All my applications (Route, Controllers, Models, and stuff) works perfect. But In CronJob doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have u installed `php-mysql`?

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: It is installed. All my applications (Route, Controllers, Models, and stuff) works perfect. But In CronJob doesn't work.